# Use CTE and Window Function to get the number of hiring under a budget

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.6

I have a table `candidates` in which there are three columns `id`, `position`, and `salary`.

The code to generate the table is

```
create table candidates (
id int primary key,
position varchar not null,
salary int not null
);
insert into candidates values (1, 'junior', 10500);
insert into candidates values (2, 'senior', 15000);
insert into candidates values (3, 'senior', 35000);
insert into candidates values (4, 'junior', 8000);
insert into candidates values (5, 'senior', 30000);
insert into candidates values (6, 'senior', 25000);
insert into candidates values (7, 'junior', 30000);
insert into candidates values (8, 'senior', 50000);
insert into candidates values (9, 'senior', 30000);
insert into candidates values (10, 'junior', 7000);
insert into candidates values (11, 'junior', 8000);
insert into candidates values (12, 'senior', 33000);
insert into candidates values (13, 'junior', 5000);
insert into candidates values (14, 'senior', 47000);
insert into candidates values (15, 'junior', 12000);
```

I have a budget of 150000 and I need to hire as many low-cost seniors as possible, and with the remaining money, I can hire as many juniors as possible. I wrote this code to get the cumulative sum of money for seniors and juniors.

```
SELECT id, position, salary, SUM(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY position ORDER BY salary) AS cum_salary
FROM candidates
ORDER BY position DESC, salary;
```

The output I get is

| id | position | salary | cum_salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | senior | 15000 | 15000 |
| 6 | senior | 25000 | 40000 |
| 5 | senior | 30000 | 100000 |
| 9 | senior | 30000 | 100000 |
| 12 | senior | 33000 | 133000 |
| 3 | senior | 35000 | 168000 |
| 14 | senior | 47000 | 215000 |
| 8 | senior | 50000 | 265000 |
| 13 | junior | 5000 | 5000 |
| 10 | junior | 7000 | 12000 |
| 11 | junior | 8000 | 28000 |
| 4 | junior | 8000 | 28000 |
| 1 | junior | 10500 | 38500 |
| 15 | junior | 12000 | 50500 |
| 7 | junior | 30000 | 80500 |

I can see that I can use 133000 (which is less than 150000) to hire 5 seniors and use the rest of the money (150000 - 133000 = 17000) to hire two juniors. So, the final output should be something like

| senior | 5 |
| --- | --- |
| junior | 2 |

How can I write this query using CTE and Window Function in POSTGRESQL 9.6 to get the kind of output I need for larger datasets, where it will not always be possible to do it manually?

PS: I am not an expert user of Postgres 9.6.

Comment: *I am not an expert user of Postgres 9.6.* Nor should you be. Experts don't use Postgres 9.6 any more since it has reached EOL last year. Upgrade to a current version!  https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Sometimes the organizations are slow to implement changes. In any case, do you have an idea of how to solve this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT position, salary
        , sum(salary)  OVER w AS cum_salary
        , row_number() OVER w AS count
   FROM   candidates
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY position ORDER BY salary)
   )
, sen AS (
   SELECT position, cum_salary, count
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  position = 'senior'
   AND    cum_salary <= 150000
   ORDER  BY cum_salary DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
SELECT position, count FROM sen
UNION ALL
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT position, count
FROM   cte
WHERE  position = 'junior'
AND    cum_salary <= (SELECT 150000 - cum_salary FROM sen)
ORDER  BY cum_salary DESC
LIMIT  1
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4b4d055811a00cb79a4471f76899e161)*

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can hardcode the amount the CTE would look like the below.
PS: You had a good start. There also may be a way to optimize the code below. Good luck ;)

```
with seniors as (
  SELECT
        id
      , position
      , salary
      , SUM(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY position ORDER BY salary) AS cum_salary
  FROM candidates
  where position = 'senior'
)
,juniors as (
  SELECT
        id
      , position
      , salary
      , SUM(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY position ORDER BY salary) AS cum_salary
  FROM candidates
  where position = 'junior'
)
,seniors_canhire as (
  select
        id
      , position
      , salary
  from seniors
  where cum_salary <= 150000
)
,juniors_canhire as (
  SELECT
        id
      , position
      , salary
  FROM juniors
  where cum_salary <= (select 150000-sum(salary) from seniors_canhire)
)
select *
from seniors_canhire
union all
select *
from juniors_canhire
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH Cte1 AS 
    (SELECT position, SUM(salary) OVER(ORDER BY salary) AS cum_salary
    FROM candidates
    WHERE position = 'senior'),

cte2 AS
    (SELECT position, SUM(salary) OVER(ORDER BY salary) AS cum_salary
    FROM candidates
    WHERE position = 'junior'),

cte3 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(position) AS seniors
    FROM cte1
     WHERE cum_salary <= 150000),

cte4 AS
    (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(cum_salary) IS NOT NULL THEN 150000 - 
    MAX(cum_salary) ELSE 150000 END AS bal_budget
    FROM cte1
    WHERE cum_salary <= 150000),

cte5 AS
    (SELECT COUNT(position) AS juniors
    FROM cte2
    WHERE cum_salary <= (SELECT bal_budget FROM cte4))

SELECT juniors, seniors
FROM cte3, cte5
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

select * from (
SELECT
COUNT(id) AS Juniors
FROM (SELECT id,position,SUM(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY position ORDER BY salary,id ASC) AS RN FROM Candidates) CTE
WHERE position = 'junior' AND RN <= (SELECT 150000 - IFNULL(MAX(RN),0) FROM (SELECT id,position,SUM(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY position ORDER BY salary,id ASC) AS RN FROM Candidates) CTE WHERE position = 'senior' AND RN < 150000))a
cross join
(SELECT  COUNT(position) AS Seniors FROM (SELECT id,position,SUM(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY position ORDER BY salary,id ASC) AS RN FROM Candidates)CTE WHERE position = 'senior' AND RN <= 150000) b

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).